# Nakama - Where can I find developer console of Google computing engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-app-engine, game-engine, digital-ocean, nakama

I was following this [tutorial](https://blog.heroiclabs.com/setting-up-a-game-server-using-nakama-on-google-compute-engine-part-2-a28cf8a0fdb2) to deploy Nakama on the Google instance, it looks it is running, but how can I open Nakama developer console now? I tryed address {my_instance_ip}:7350 at it is blank page. In all the offical matterails is port 7351, but when I tryed {my_instance_ip}:7350, the page is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it by myself, I didnt have firewall rule for the port 7351. So to answer my question - just rewrite tcp:7350 in the tutorial to tcp:7350,7351.